# Heavy calculations on a background thread in getter

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I need to perform a lot of calculations every time a getter is called from my app. The data returned from the getter is constantly changing based on the environment, and it has to do a lot of calculations to compute what it should return. Therefore, I don't want the code in the getter running on the main thread. This is what I have so far:

```
@interface Calculator ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t calculationThread;
@end

- (dispatch_queue_t)calculationThread {
    if (!_calculationThread) {
        _calculationThread = dispatch_queue_create("calculation_thread", NULL);
    }
    return _calculationThread;
}

- (NSArray *)calculation {
    // perform calculation in calculationThread, which should not be on main thread and be asynchronous
    return arrayContainingCalculations;
}
```

I basically want to know how to use GCD to replace the comment. I have tried using dispatch_queue_t and dispatch_group_notify, but I don't seem to be implementing it correctly.

Comment: Asynchronous by definition means that it will not wait for your getter code to execute before returning a value. As Peter says, you'll need to setup some form of callback block or delegate for the asynchronous code. Either that, or you invoke the getter from a background thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think using a callback is probably the simplest and most efficient solution to this problem.**

It is simply *impossible* to use only a single getter to do an asynchronous calculation without blocking the thread it was called on, as you expect code called after it to continue executing while it does the calculation.

You just have to create a new method with a callback, for example:

```
-(void) doCalculation:(void(^)(NSArray* result))callback {
    dispatch_async(self.calculationQueue, ^{

        NSArray* result = self.calculation; // make sure this is doing a synchronous calculation. If it's asynchronous, you'll have to use a semaphore (or another callback!).

        if (callback) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // return to main thread
                callback(result);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can simply invoke it on your main thread like so:

```
[calculator doCalculation:^(NSArray* result) {
    textView.text = [result[0] stringValue]; // update UI with new info.
}];
```

That way you can easily keep your resulting code in-line with the call to the method.

It's also worth noting that your `calculationQueue`'s getter (I renamed it, as the word thread is misleading when you're working with queues) isn't thread-safe. I would advise you use a `dispatch_once` to make it thread-safe:

```
-(dispatch_queue_t) calculationQueue {

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _calculationQueue = dispatch_queue_create("calculation_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    });

    return _calculationQueue;
}
```

Comment: Looks like OP has checked out, but this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to put it on your queue asynchronously. The problem however is that the method is going to return immediately.

```
dispatch_async(your_queue, ^{
    // Code to be executed on background thread
});
```

What you probably want is to have some kind of method `calculateWithCompletion` where the caller can define a block that you can invoke once the completion is finished.

Comment: I would like to keep the interface as self.calculation if possible

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comment to Peter, you want to keep it so you can call `self.calculation` and get your logic executed and return the calculation synchronously.

However because you want to avoid locking the UI while this logic is executing, you would like it to execute on a background thread.

Therefore, all you should need to do is use `dispatch_sync` instead of `dispatch_async` inside of your `calculate` method.

What `dispatch_sync` does is it places a task (the block that contains your logic) onto a specified queue (probably should pick a [global concurrent queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW5)), which then executes your task on a thread the OS picks for you (not the main thread).  `dispatch_async` does the same, **Except** that `dispatch_async` will continue execution immediately after dispatching your task onto a queue.

`dispatch_sync` on the other hand, will block execution in the current run loop until your tasks returns.

This will allow you to execute your expensive logic on a background thread, while still remaining synchronous so that you can continue using `self.calculation`

Comment: this will only work if OP invokes the getter on a background thread *to begin with*, as `dispatch_sync` will block the main thread if the getter is called from there.

Comment: Ah yes sorry you're right, brain fart for me.  OP has a couple choices, wrap the entire calculation logic *as well as* the caller in a `dispatch_async`, or add a callback as Peter suggested